# storage limit for the arguments/variables in python

Tags: c, assembly, python-3.x

For the below program

```
def sum_naturals(n):
    total, k = 0, 1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + k, k + 1
    return total

sum_naturals(5000000000000000000000)
```

from past 20 minutes, am waiting for the output from processor intel t1400 1.83 ghz.

My question is,

how does python handle such a big data, because my processor has only 32 bit registers? C prograam would have given error very early?

Sham

Answer (score 0):

Python's int type supports arbitrarily large numbers. Internally, there's two representations: a single machine int for small numbers, and an array of ints for larger ones (and the sign, which is stored separately). The array represents the digits of the number in a large base.

Comment: The internal distinction (which is not really internal actually, as the two are distinct Python types and are displayed differently) is gone in 3.x though, where all integers are arbitrary precision.

Comment: hello delnan                                        well python does not need typing of a variable as language,  i think u are talking about internals of python interpreter, where integer is stored as array to handle huge values. But is there any limit for integer value in python for example  in c language 32 bit it is -2^15-1 to 2^15-1.                        Sham

Comment: for your statement: "a single machine int for small numbers, and an array of ints for larger ones (and the sign, which is stored separately)."                                              Are you saying that integers are not stored in 2's complement form in python?